# Find the expected values: $\mathbb{E}[X^Y] , \mathbb{E}[2^{X - 5\cdot Y}]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

> Let $X$ be a geometric variable with parameter $p \in ]1,2[ $ and $Y$ bernoulli distributed with the same parameter p.
>   Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, find the following expected values:
>   $\mathbb{E}[X^Y] , \mathbb{E}[2^{X - 5\cdot Y}]$

Comment: Hint: use $\mathbb{E}[X^Y] = \mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}[X^Y | Y ]]$

Comment: or  $\mathbb{E}[X^Y] = \mathbb{E}[X^01_{Y=0}] + \mathbb{E}[X^11_{Y=1}]$ and $\mathbb{E}[2^{X-5Y}] = \mathbb{E}[2^{X}1_{Y=0}] + \mathbb{E}[2^{X-5}1_{Y=1}]$. Then use independance.

Comment: How probability $p$ can take values from $]1,\,2[$?

Comment: I removed the [tag:geometric-probability] and [tag:probability-theory] tags. Please read the tag descriptions when using tags.